# TimerCallBack Method Name excepted Error

Tags: c#

I could not understand why I got an Error

This is my start Method in my Engine class.

```
    private void Start()
    {
        Engine engine = new Engine();

        engineThrottleLock = new object();

        TimerCallback tcb = new TimerCallback(EngineRpmTimer());

        timer = new Timer(tcb, null, 0, 0);
    }
```

And here is my engineThrottleLock method also in my Engine class

```
    private void EngineRpmTimer()
    {
        lock (engineThrottleLock)
        {
            if (rpm > 800)
            {
                rpm -= 700;
            }
            else
            {
                rpm = 100;
            }
            SendRpmValueToChip();
            SendHighRevolutionWarningToChip();
        }

    }
```

In this line :

```
    TimerCallback tcb = new TimerCallback(EngineRpmTimer());
```

Visual Studio says that ERROR : Method name excepted.

Actually, I wrote an method name. But probably I was missed a small step :( 
Do you guys have any idea ?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis: `new TimerCallback(EngineRpmTimer);` With parenthesis it's not a method name, but a method _call_

Comment: @RenéVogt place the comment as an answer before anyone else does, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the parenthesis:

```
TimerCallback tcb = new TimerCallback(EngineRpmTimer); // <- no parenthesis
```

With parenthesis it's a **call to the method**, and that method does not return the correct type (a valid callback method).

Without parenthesis it's the correct method **name**.

Comment: THANKS BRO !! That's true. Sorry I took your time for that small mistake :(

Comment: @AhmetBatuOrhan You're welcome, but I'd vote to close this question because it's only a typo. (if you want you can mark this answer as "accepted" anyway).

Comment: Okay bro, I will delete this question :)